# How to solve Empty Dataframe problem when I merge two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following is my code:

```
np.random.seed(0)
left = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})    
right = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})
print(pd.merge(left,right))
```

The result is:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [key, value]
Index: []
```

I don't know why they are empty.

Comment: What data is in your dataframes? Maybe there are no matching values between them?

Comment: Use `on=` parameter: `print(pd.merge(left,right, on='key'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the column on which to join like this:

```
>>> pd.merge(left, right, on='key')
  key   value_x   value_y
0   B  0.400157  1.867558
1   D  2.240893 -0.977278
```

If you require all keys:

```
>>> pd.merge(left, right, on='key', how='outer')
  key   value_x   value_y
0   A  1.764052       NaN
1   B  0.400157  1.867558
2   C  0.978738       NaN
3   D  2.240893 -0.977278
4   E       NaN  0.950088
5   F       NaN -0.151357
```